# Softwares for visualizing $2$-dimensional CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

Are there any softwares that help visualize a CW-complex?
My input data is a combinatorially defined cell structure on non-orientable surfaces. In particular I know the number of cells (the $2$-cells are regular polygons) and the attaching maps.

Comment: If you have a picture in mind, how your CW complex looks like, you should use Maple or similar software to visualize the complex by using algebraic terms which describe your set. Personally I don't know a special software for CW complexes.